# Could anyone help me check my grammar in sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, writing-critique

请多多指教  I'm just a beginner

- 这是谁的手机不知道呢
- 你想吃什么随便呢
- 我想发电子邮件向妈妈
- 请在这里等我
- 我有急事，请您接替我的职位，可以吗？
- 我想我的行李箱忘在出租车上了
- 云岘宫是韩国名胜古迹之一
- 你专心学习，当然不会考不及格的
- 她不知道怎样使用提款机
- 上次他们问了我没回应
- 要是我有一百万，我要买汽车给父母
- 请等他一会儿
- 妈妈希望我成功
- 我们要万事如意
- 我的理想是会说汉语
- 专业是政治学
- 大清早我还很困
- 让我们一起在主里面的层间
- 你熟悉这个女人吗?
- 昨天我偶然遇见老朋友了呢

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello! Please ask one question at a time, giving your own translation and explaining where and why you perceive that a sentence has grammatical issues.

Comment: Indeed. I suggest: 1. Choose one sentence and ask about that [highlight what is difficult and what it's meant to mean].  2. Learn from the answers you get.  3. Choose another sentence then ask about that, using what you've learned from the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

- *不知道* 这是谁的手机呢
- 你想吃什么呢
- 我想 *向妈妈* 发电子邮件
- 请在这里等我
- 我有急事，请您接替我的职位，可以吗？
- 我想我的行李箱 *留* 在出租车上了
- 云岘宫是韩国名胜古迹之一
- *只要* 你专心学习，*就* 不会考不及格
- 她不知道 *如何* 使用提款机
- 要是我有一百万，我要买汽车给父母
- 请等他一会儿
- 妈妈希望我成功
- 我们要万事如意
- 我的理想是会说汉语
- *政治学* 是 *专业*
- 让我们一起在 *住* 里面的层间
- 你 *對这个女人* 熟悉吗?
- 昨天我遇见老朋友了呢

Comment: Thank you so much❤

Answer (score 0):

- 这是谁的手机不知道呢 -> 不知道这是谁的手机呢？
- 你想吃什么随便呢 you can use this oral speaking, it means "you can eat whatever you want"
- 我想发电子邮件向妈妈 -> 我想发电子邮件给妈妈 This is idiomatic.
- 请在这里等我
- 我有急事，请您接替我的职位，可以吗？
- 我想我的行李箱忘在出租车上了
- 云岘宫是韩国名胜古迹之一
- 你专心学习，当然不会考不及格的
- 她不知道怎样使用提款机
- 上次他们问了我没回应 -> 上次他们问了,我没回应
- 要是我有一百万，我要买汽车给父母
- 请等他一会儿
- 妈妈希望我成功
- > 我们要万事如意

  万事如意 can't be use like that.
- 我的理想是会说汉语
- 专业是政治学 If you want to mean your major or other people's major is politics, you must put a subject at the beginning, such as my major is politics (我的专业是政治学）
- 大清早我还很困
- 让我们一起在主里面的层间 -> 让我们一起住在里面的房间
- 你熟悉这个女人吗?
- 昨天我偶然遇见老朋友了呢 You can say that in oral speaking. For writing, you'd better use 昨天我偶然遇见老朋友了

Answer (score 0):

这是谁的手机？我不知道呢！ or 我不知道这是谁的手机呢！

你想吃什么？随便呢！

我想向妈妈发电子邮件。

请在这里等我。

我有急事，请您接替我的职位，可以吗？

我想我的行李箱忘在出租车上了。

云岘宫是韩国名胜古迹之一。

你专心学习，当然不会考不及格的。 or 当然会及格的。

她不知道怎样使用提款机。

上次他们问了我，我没回应。

要是我有一百万，我要给父母买汽车。

请等他一会儿。

妈妈希望我成功。

祝我们万事如意！

我的理想是会说汉语。

政治学是专业。

大清早我还很困。

让我们一起住里面的层间。 or 让我们一起在里面的层间住。

你熟悉这个女人吗?

昨天我偶然遇见老朋友了呢！

Punctuation, word order, composition, all have problems.